# Decouple Caller from Subscriber Class

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, events, unity-container

I am trying to achieve something that I do not know if is possible.

**Background:** I am creating a new ASP.NET MVC 3 Project and I want to move the Unity container initialization outside of the Web Project.

**Intention:** I want my Web Project to be decoupled from the project that contains the Unity Container Initialization code.

**My Solution:** Have Class A in a separate project publish an event through delegate/event declaration and expose a method that raises the event.

Have another Class B in a separate project that subscribes to the event that Class A publishes.

Have Global.asax in my Web Project initialize Class A and call the method that raises the event.

**Expectation:** I want the event handler method in the subscriber class (Class B) to be executed as soon as the event is raised.

The Web Project references the library that contains Class A (Publisher). The Library that contains Class B (Subscriber) also references  the library that contains Class A.

Is there a way to achieve this and if not what other suggestions do you have for me, in order to avoid initializing the Unity Container in the Web Project?

Answer (score 0):

Since I have not been able to do this and since I have not heard from anyone else I am answering my own question: What I am trying to do is not possible.